# Monitor connected to CPU slower than those from GPU

Tags: multiple-monitors, vim

I have two monitors connected to my GPU and a single monitor connected to my CPU / motherboard.

In general use (internet, folders, etc), performance on all monitors is pretty similar. When I'm using vim on the monitor connected to the CPU it is very laggy.

Why is this an issue? Why does vim specifically suffer from the set-up?

I've tried getting all monitors to work from the GPU but stuff like daisy chaining the monitors with display port or mini DP cables resulted in monitors being duplicated not separate screens.

Ubuntu 18.04
Radeon HD 8570

Comment: Have you tried to clear your vimrc? How is this 'lagginess' shown (scrolling, cursor or what?). I think it have something to do with gpu rendering (yes, your 3rd display is also connected to GPU, not CPU). Are you using vim on terminal or graphical app?

Comment: What do you mean clear my vimrc? When I use vim commands they are laggy to have effect -- e.g. new line commands, paste commands, typing in insert mode. This is using vim in the terminal

Comment: vimrc is vim config file, user settings are in home directory located vimrc and a system wide vimrc usually in /etc/vimrc or /etc/vim/vimrc. Vim is really flexible and easy to mess up with configuring. Is other terminal programs affected?

Comment: Yeh sorry I know what the vimrc is but I want the commands that I've set up in my vimrc, and it works fine on my other monitors so I don't see why clearing it would help? What are some other terminal programs to try?

Comment: Okay seems the real issue is just the new line command -- it is laggy so any commands (e.g. pasting and typing) after it are also laggy.

Comment: Copy the vimrc file to somewhere safe and try clearing it. As I said, vim is easy to mess laggy via configuring. Other terminal programs you can try as text editor is nano.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91887/discussion-between-jamie-and-pasi-suominen).

Comment: for help see https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file/2004#2004

Comment: Should I delete this post? Issue is related to python.vim file in vim/indent/ folder